# Youtube video Insert Button not appearing in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I added Youtube plugin in CKEditor and according to instruction on page added the code in config.js but it did not show the youtube insert button on toolbar.

I downloaded and extracted the Youtube plugin to folder and the added following code to config.js

```
config.extraPlugins = "plugin1,plugin2,youtube";
```

but it did not show in toolbar. I added the it in items in toolbar also like

```
{ name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format','youtube' ] }
```

But insert button did not appear in toolbar.

Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I had to use capital letter 'Y' as Youtube when adding it to toolbar like:

```
 { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Youtube'] }
```

and "y" small letter 'y' as youtube when adding in extraPlugins

```
config.extraPlugins = "plugin1,plugin2,youtube";
```

not sure why its missing in instructions given on plugin page but this is how it worked for me.